# Calculating inverse of transposition key cipher

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

I need some help on transposition cryptography.

If I'm given the encoding key to a transposition cipher, how do I get the decoding key for it? I tried googling but couldn't find any steps on the calculation for it. For example, like in [this](http://bionsgadgets.appspot.com/gadget_forms/get_inverse_key.html) website, when I enter 
 `4 3 1 6 2 5` I would get `3 5 2 1 6 4` but why and how?